# Finding duplicates to prepare for a two-column primary key

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have been using a two-column primary key but I've just found out that the second column (column 2) has values that map to the same item leading to duplication.

I have created a new column (column 3) from which I want to create a two-column primary key. I need to prepare the database for the new primary key by deleting the duplicate line items.

I am looking for a query that can isolate the duplicate columns: e.g. where both column 1 and column 3 are duplicates. E.g.

```
Column 1   Column 2   Column 3   Remove?
1          a          x          n
1          b          x          y
2          b          y          n
3          c          z          n
3          d          z          y
3          e          z          y
4          f          x          n
```

Note it doesn't matter which of the column values I keep since they are equivalent is column 3 is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull out data that you would like to retain, by grouping on your key columns, and using MIN() or MAX() on the other columns [since you say you do not care which value of you keep, from Column 2].

```
Select Column1, Column3, MAX(Column2) As Column2
from Table1
Group By  Column1, Column2
```

Put that in a temp table, then remove all records from your original table and replace with everything in the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to delete duplicate rows in your table by creating a new table. Assuming your original table name (with the duplicates) is `tbl`, you should after running this query end up with two tables in your database: `tbl` that is the new table without the duplicates, and `tbl_old` that is the original table (just renamed):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_unique LIKE tbl;
  ALTER TABLE tbl_unique
  ADD UNIQUE KEY unkey(C1,C3);

INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_unique
  SELECT * FROM tbl;

ALTER TABLE tbl RENAME tbl_old;
ALTER TABLE tbl_unique RENAME tbl;
```

Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da167/1/0

Source:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/deleting-duplicates-with-group-by-and-count